# What causes a freely placed bead on a vertical circular loop, spinning horizontally about its vertical axis, to move upward?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, rotational-dynamics

When observed from the ground frame (assuming no friction is present), the only forces that act on the rotating bead are weight and the normal force exerted by the loop towards the center of the loop. I suppose there is no component of the normal force in the direction of the bead's movement, so it shouldn't move upwards. I am unable to comprehend why the bead does move upward.[image]

Comment: Does "upward" suppose a gravitational field? Which bead are you talking about, that moves upwards in a gravitational field? And please be clear: is one spin axis horizontal ("a vertical circular loop"), and another spin axis vertical ("spinning horizontally around its vertical axis")?

Comment: I am attaching an image to make my question more clear.

Comment: Perhaps caused by a precession effect: but it will only move upwards if a) an external force is applied, or b) energy is lost, or (c) the motion is oscillatory. Possibly related is [what goes up must come down](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/547868/how-does-the-equivalence-principle-explain-what-goes-up-must-come-down).